# How to apply to multiple filenames in Windows command line?

Tags: command-line, regex, tar, window

I'm using `tar` in Windows 10 command line to extract a specific file from a bunch of archives.
I'm quite experienced in regex, but I have very little experience in Windows commands.
I'm using [this manual](https://ss64.com/nt/tar.html), which proved robust so far.

In the archive, I'm interested in extracting 2 files: `NAMESPACE` and `DESCRIPTION`.

Extracting those separately works fine:

```
tar -xzvf "path/to/my/archive.tar.gz" *NAMESPACE
tar -xzvf "path/to/my/archive.tar.gz" *DESCRIPTION
```

I'm using `*` as the files are located in irrelevant, changing subdirectories.

However, as this script will run a very large amount of times (and for the sake of doing well also), I would like to run it in only one command.

Unfortunately, my tries so far did not work:

```
tar -xzvf "path/to/my/archive.tar.gz" *NAMESPACE||DESCRIPTION
tar -xzvf "path/to/my/archive.tar.gz" *(NAMESPACE||DESCRIPTION)
tar -xzvf "path/to/my/archive.tar.gz" *NAMESPACE||*DESCRIPTION
```

Is there a way to compact these 2 commands?

Comment: Did you try `tar -xzvf "path/to/my/archive.tar.gz" *NAMESPACE *DESCRIPTION` ?

Comment: that's the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command :

```
tar -xzvf "path/to/my/archive.tar.gz" *NAMESPACE *DESCRIPTION
```

Comment: So simple at last! Any chance you could guide me on how I could have found this info myself? My google-fu was pretty weak on that...

Comment: Sorry, no complicated google-fu - I examined the manpage of tar, so found that it accepts multiple file names.